# Plotting mixtures of distributions with Julia

Tags: julia, distribution, gaussian, mixture-model

I want to plotting mixtures of two 1d Gaussian distributions with Julia. I am not sure what is the best way to do it. I am trying to use `Distributions.jl` and in specific to both

- Define two Gaussians using `d1 = Normal(0.0, 1.0)` and `d2 = Normal(1.0, 1.8)`
- Define a mixture using
  `MixtureModel(Normal[ Normal(-2.0, 1.2), Normal(0.0, 1.0), Normal(3.0, 2.5)], [0.1, 0.6, 0.3])`

Now, for the 1st attempt I do not know how to define the weights. My questions therefore is about **how to proceed on to simply generate and draw samples of this mixture**?

I would like to plot them and also use these samples in order to perform parameter estimation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question - why are you defining `d1` and `d2`?

To answer your bold question: just use `rand()` to draw from your mixture distribution:

```
julia> using Distributions

julia> mm = MixtureModel([Normal(-2.0, 1.2), Normal(), Normal(3.0, 2.5)], [0.1, 0.6, 0.3])
MixtureModel{Normal{Float64}}(K = 3)
components[1] (prior = 0.1000): Normal{Float64}(μ=-2.0, σ=1.2)
components[2] (prior = 0.6000): Normal{Float64}(μ=0.0, σ=1.0)
components[3] (prior = 0.3000): Normal{Float64}(μ=3.0, σ=2.5)

julia> rand(mm)
1.882130062980293
```

Note that here I have used `Normal()` instead of `Normal(0.0, 1.0)`, as `Normal()` already returns the standard normal distribution.

To plot:

```
julia> using Plots

julia> histogram(rand(mm, 100_000), normalize = true, xlabel = "Value", ylabel = "Frequency", label = "Mixture model")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. This is very helpful.  I managed to do it slightly differently.